# openoffice headless commands documentation/references

Tags: php, linux, command-line, openoffice.org

anyone can point me to documentation/tutorials of how to use the openoffice headless version for document conversions? (from ppt to pdf, from doc to pdf etc..)

and if is there any hint of how to use it with php, even better :)

Regards,
Shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a PHP module written to interface with the Open Office programming API called [PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05) that would be a useful first step. Instructions for configuring OO and building PUNO can be found [here](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05,03)